# What is an event when user changes items of combobox in WPF 2010

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a populated combobox. I would like to show MessageBox if a focus changes from one item to another item of a ComboBox. But ComboBox must not be closed, that is user just goes through items in ComboBox, but user does not push a left button its mouse:).

For example, a combobox has three items - "x1", "x2" and "x3". If user selects "x1" then I want to show MessageBox.Show("x1") and if user selects "x2" then I want to show MessageBox.Show("It is amazing!")

How to do it? Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use event of Combobox named "DropDownClosed" so I can catch the latest choice of user and read its choise.

Comment: What if they change the selection without ever dropping down (and therefore without closing) the combobox?

Comment: It is possible to read what user chosen if they do not use dropping down. I read what they chosen in the end of selected data:).